# I think I'm being Hacked....what to do?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a compute engine instance, today going over the outputs i see that for the last 20 days someone is trying to hack my server the user name changes constantly bit the ip stays the same

```
Invalid user liao from xxx.xxx.x.xxx
input_userauth_request: invalid user liao [preauth]
Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.x.xxx: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

what can I do to protect my server, how can I know if there was a successful entry?

Comment: please let me know why this question is being down voted and getting close votes...if there are steps to take to make it better I'd be happy to follow suggestions

Answer (score 4):

You're not being hacked; just like every server that exposes port 22, you're being scanned.

If you use simple passwords, you could eventually be hacked indeed.

Here's what you can do (in order of priority):

- Disable password authentication on your host, and only use SSH key authentication. It's unlikely (read impossible) that a scanner would guess a SSH key.
- Block connections to port 22 (using GCE firewalls) from IPs that you don't own (could be difficult if you dont have a static IP)
- Change your SSH port to something not default

Comment: I'm using SSH, also my port is not default as for static IP requests are coming from all over as I'm supplying API services to mobile application.

Comment: @liva I think you misunderstood everything I said. You should change your SSH authentication method, change your SSH port, and change your firewall rules for your SSH port. None of this has to do with your API service.

Comment: @liva Also, if you don't understand any of this, the best approach for you might be to use a PaaS (such as Google App Engine or Heroku), or hire a sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks I did understand what you ment on the fist time :), I would love to use PaaS (it would have been much cheaper), unfortunately I can't!